# NameError: uninitialized constant in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm adding a 'questions' table to my database...when I migrated it...everything seemed fine.
BUT when I go into rails console...it tells me 'NameError: uninitialized constant Question'

what am I missing? Here is my migration output, migration file data, and rails console error.

I'm a beginner at Rails so please forgive my noobness.

So I got this after my rake db:migrate...

```
    Zach:FundAnEd zach$ rake db:migrate 
    ==  DropQuestionTable: migrating ==============================================
    -- drop_table(:questions)
       -> 0.0490s
    ==  DropQuestionTable: migrated (0.0492s) =====================================

    ==  CreateQuestions: migrating ================================================
    -- create_table(:questions)
       -> 0.0161s
    -- add_index(:questions, :scholarship_id)
       -> 0.0254s
    ==  CreateQuestions: migrated (0.0417s) =======================================
```

and this is my migration file content...

```
    class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :questions do |t|
          t.string :question_type
          t.references :scholarship
          t.string :question_title

          t.timestamps
        end
        add_index :questions, :scholarship_id
      end
    end
```

AND here is the error I'm getting....

```
    NameError: uninitialized constant Question
        from (irb):1
        from /Users/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /Users/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /Users/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a Question model? If yes, include its code.

Comment: what you do before you get error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to make sure you have a Question model, plus if you have it then make sure you have followed proper naming conventions, models in ruby on rails are singular means the model name would be "Question" not "Questions". hope it would help

Comment: Thanks. I got it figured out

Comment: if it had solved your problem you can accept the answer thanks

Comment: Can you please mention, what did you figure out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I had same problem because I didn't have the corresponding model defined. This answer got me right.